# Serializing JSON (System.Text.Json) to GZipStream and MemoryStream

Tags: json, .net, amazon-s3, system.text.json

I have object in memory which I want to serialize using `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` while compressing data (and keeping stream for later use, specifically to be passed to S3 SDK to be put into storage, using `Stream InputStream`).

```cs
await using var stream = new MemoryStream(); // <- compressed content stored here
await using var gzip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal); // <- compression

await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(gzip, myObject); // <- serialize
gzip.Flush(); // <- make sure everything is flushed
```

At this point `stream` contains compressed binary data of JSON serialized `myObject`. In the end, I would like to store this data to a file - either locally or to S3 (using `Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility` passing `stream` to `InputStream` property).

- how can I save content to a file (using file stream produces invalid `.gz` file)?
- how can I specify file(name) to which content is placed within `.gz` package?

Answer (score 0):

> - how can I save content to a file (using file stream produces invalid .gz file)?

You need to set the position of the `MemoryStream` back to `0` otherwise there is nothing to read.

```cs
stream.Position = 0;
await using (var file = new FileStream(@"someFile.gz", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
stream.Position = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can use the underlying array inside the stream, which is likely to be more efficient. You should still reset the stream position before sending it to S3.

```cs
await using (var file = new FileStream(@"someFile.gz", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    await file.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.Length);
}
stream.Position = 0;
```

Note the use of braces to flush and close the file properly before the end of the function. You should do that instead of `Flush`.

> - how can I specify file(name) to which content is placed within .gz package?

You can't. There is no mechanism within the *gzip* spec to add a filename, it's designed for compressing a single file. Normally you would produce a *tarball* first, alternatively use `ZipArchive` which uses a similar compression algorithm.